# Django validate model forms

Tags: django

I changed my all post.

I can't deal with raising errors in my template. I wrote clean method for my form:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    subcategory = cleaned_data['subcategory']
    subcategory1 = cleaned_data['subcategory1']
    if subcategory1 and (subcategory == subcategory1):
        raise forms.ValidationError("ERROR")
    else:
        print('OKKKKKKKKKK')
```

My view:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form_extended = SiteAddFormFull(request.POST)
    if form_extended.is_valid():
        form_extended.save()
        messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Success!!')
    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Error!!')
        print(form_extended.errors)
```

Why when I open my form view I get "OKKKKKKKKKK" (in terminal) from my clean(self) method and in my template view 'Error!!' appears...? I would like to show error from my clean method but I don't now how to do it....

Comment: What's the issue? Is this not validating? You didn't ask a question.

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake. I edited my post.

Comment: If your indentation is correct you have added the `clean()` method to the `Meta` class of the form, not to the form itself.

Answer (score 0):

If your formatting is right then your `clean` method is in the `Meta` class of your `ModelForm` class. Try to ident it back so it belongs to your `ModelForm` class not to its meta class, for example, like this:

```
class YourCustomModelForm(django.forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = ('url', 'name', 'description', 'keywords', 'group', 'category',
              'subcategory', 'category1', 'subcategory1')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(YourCustomModelForm, self).clean()
        subcategory = cleaned_data['subcategory']
        subcategory1 = cleaned_data['subcategory1']
        if subcategory == subcategory1:
            raise forms.ValidationError('ERROR')
```

Comment: Don't know but calling parent classes' methods with `super()` without providing parameters also maybe the issue. You are trying to call `ModelForm`s `clean` method with `super().clean()` which is not recommended.

Comment: If no success, try to access your `cleaned_data` with `self.cleaned_data`. For more info look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Comment: I changed subcategory = cleaned_data['subcategory'] to subcategory = cleaned_data['url'] and it works. I don't know why I can't validate subcategory field. It raises key error...